# What is the statement which I have to give in isql so that autocommit is off?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I use sybase ase 16. What is the statement which I have to give in isql so that autocommit is off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set chained on`         -- enable chained transaction mode (aka autocommit off)

`set chained off`        -- disable chained transaction mode (aka autocommit on); default in ASE

`select @@tranchained`   -- see current mode (0=unchained;1=chained)

`isql -Y`                -- connect to ASE with chained enabled;  default (ie, no '-Y') is chained disabled